# Changing operators in Prolog

Tags: prolog

The lecture talked about operators and their priority. While the task is at a beginner level, I am having trouble wrapping my head around where to even find the logic.

The task is to change operators with a    met/2     predicate:

```
?- met(q+w+e,Y).       
Y=q-w-e. 

?- met(q-w-e,Y).
Y=q+w+e.
```

I don't mind if people nudge me the right way or give the answer straightout. I've googled this for a while now and found nothing. I tried if-then, but it didn't work.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Prolog term can be represented as a tree. For example, for the term `q+w+e`, and assuming the standard operator definition for the infix operator `(+)/2` we have:

```
?- write_canonical(q+w+e).
+(+(q,w),e)
true.
```

Now, if you have a tree, you can *traverse* it and do the transformation you require at each non-leaf node. A *partial* solution:

```
met('+'(Left, Right), '-'(TLeft, TRight)) :-
    met(Left, TLeft),
    met(Right, TRight).
```

Comment: Only a very small addition to this good answer for OP: We can write the clause head without single quotes as `met(+(Left, Right), -(TLeft, TRight)) :- ...`, and using infix operators as: `met(Left+Right, TLeft-TRight) :- ...`. These are equivalent notations for the same terms.

Comment: Operator notation is handy and, when dealing with standard operators, usually safe. On the other hand, avoiding dependencies on the specifics of operator declarations *and* the quirks of Prolog parsers can result in more robust and portable code. But above was simply a case of emphasizing that operators are just syntax sugar.